# How to show pre existing tags using tagit?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tag-it

I'm using tag-it https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it for tagging. After creating the tags and saved, How to show  saved tags on edit? I tried availableTags option but couldn't achieve.

```
  - form_for @user_service, :user => current_user, :url => save_service_tag_user_services_url(:user_service_id => params[:user_service_id])  do |f|
    %span.error-message
    %ul{:id => "stream_add_topic"}
      %li#tag-service{:style => "width: 281px !important;"}
        #add_tag{:id=>"#{@user_service.id}"}
          .url{:style => "float:left;"}
            == Add Tag for auto-posting
            %ul{:id => "link_tags_#{@user_service.id}", :style => "width:265px", :name => "service_tags[]"}

      %li{:id => "stream_topic_text"}
        %label{:for => "topicNames"}== Select a topic
        %br/
        = f.select(:topic_id , Topic.all.collect {|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, {:prompt => 'Pick a Topic'})
    .modalConfirmAct.flRight
      .blueBtn
        =  submit_tag "Save", :class => "smlrBtn"
      .yellowBtn
        = link_to_close_redbox("#{t :cancel}", :class => "smlrBtn")

:javascript     
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#link_tags_#{@user_service.id}").tagit({  availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"] });
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Can you post the code related to it as without it it's impossible to help . Also what all did you try to achieve it

Comment: @CaffeineCoder I edited my question You can see that

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
<ul id="your_tagit_block_id">
  <% @available_tags.each do |tag| %>
    <li><%= tag.title %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it/blob/master/README.markdown#usage

Comment: when I use that am getting below issue in firebug.

TypeError: tagsAll.split is not a function 
[Break On This Error]  

var tagsArray = tagsAll.split(",")

Answer (score 0):

In model

```
class UserSerVice < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_service
end
```

in controller

```
 class UserServicesController < ApplicationController

   .....

   def edit
      @service = UserSerVice.find(params[:id])
      @tags ||= @service.tags.collect(&:name) 
   end
 end
```

in views As per tagit

```
   <ul id="myTags"></ul>

   $("#myTags").tagit({
     availableTags: ['<%=j @tags %>']
    });
```